# ReluGrad input is not finite on multi-layer network in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm doing the udacity course of TensotFlow, I'm trying to train a neural network on the notMNIST set.
When using a 1-hidden layer network all works fine, but when I try to add another layer, after ~150 steps I get this error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: ReluGrad input is not finite. : Tensor had NaN values
```

This is the network model:

```
def model(x, w_h,w_h2,w_0,b_h,b_h2,b_0,p_drop):
h = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x,w_h)+b_h)
h = tf.nn.dropout(h,p_drop)
h2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h, w_h2)+b_h2)
h2 = tf.nn.dropout(h2,p_drop)
return (tf.matmul(h2,w_0)+b_0)
```

And the error is pointing at a specific line:

```
h = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x,w_h)+b_h)
```

I guess the with two-layer network the w_h are becoming very small so the matmul product go to zero, but I don't understand how I can solve it
Notice that I'm using this optimizer:

```
net = model(tf_train_dataset,w_h,w_h2,w_0,b_h,b_h2,b_0,0.5)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(
       tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(net, tf_train_labels))
global_step = tf.Variable(0)  # count the number of steps taken.
learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(0.5, global_step, 100, 0.95)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss,global_step=global_step)
```

The net is 784->1024->512->10

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: That happens when your training diverges. Try using lower learning rate and/or different optimizer (AdamOptimizer)

Comment: I tried to lower the learning rate but then it gets stuck on a local minima...

Comment: That's normal, learning rate too high and you diverge, learning rate too low and accuracy is bad. I'd recommend using AdamOptimizer and starting with higher rate

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem when my weights were being initialized randomly and by biases with zeros. Using [Xavier and Yoshua](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v9/glorot10a/glorot10a.pdf)'s initialization solved the problem, and here is my full example:

```
hidden_size = 1024
batch_size = 256

def multilayer(x, w, b):
    for i, (wi, bi) in enumerate(zip(w, b)):
        if i == 0:
            out = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x, wi) + bi)
        elif i == len(w) - 1:
            out = tf.matmul(out, wi) + bi
        else:
            out = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(out, wi) + bi)
    print(out.shape, x.shape)
    return out

graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():

    # Input data. For the training data, we use a placeholder that will be fed
    # at run time with a training minibatch.
    tf_train_dataset = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, image_size * image_size))
    tf_train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, num_labels))
    tf_valid_dataset = tf.constant(valid_dataset)
    tf_test_dataset = tf.constant(test_dataset)

    # Defining Xavier and Yoshua's initializer
    initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()

    # Variables
    W1 = tf.Variable(initializer([image_size * image_size, hidden_size]))
    b1 = tf.Variable(initializer([hidden_size]))
    W2 = tf.Variable(initializer([hidden_size, hidden_size]))
    b2 = tf.Variable(initializer([hidden_size]))
    W3 = tf.Variable(initializer([hidden_size, hidden_size]))
    b3 = tf.Variable(initializer([hidden_size]))
    W4 = tf.Variable(initializer([hidden_size, hidden_size]))
    b4 = tf.Variable(initializer([hidden_size]))
    W5 = tf.Variable(initializer([hidden_size, num_labels]))
    b5 = tf.Variable(initializer([num_labels]))

    Ws = [W1, W2, W3, W4, W5]
    bs = [b1, b2, b3, b4, b5]

    # Training computation
    logits = multilayer(tf_train_dataset, Ws, bs)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=tf_train_labels))
    #NOTE loss is actually a scalar value that represents the effectiveness of the
    #     current prediction. A minimized loss means that the weights and biases
    #     are adjusted at their best for the training data.

    # Optimizer
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(loss)

    # Predictions for the training, validation, and test data.
    train_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
    valid_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(multilayer(tf_valid_dataset, Ws, bs))
    test_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(multilayer(tf_test_dataset, Ws, bs))
```